# How to port pgm_read_byte macro (AVR-GCC) to Mircrochip C18 Compiler?

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I'm porting the [T6963-based LCD driver](http://en.radzio.dxp.pl/t6963/) from AVR-GCC to the microchip C18 compiler. I have seen the macro "[pgm_read_byte](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html)": does anyone know how to port this macro?

**UPDATE**

From [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fidE0465E75E0EDBBCF1855F09FF4A43B8518C4346D.aspx) I can see the implementation of the macro

```
#define   pgm_read_byte(address_short)
pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)
...
#define   pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)   __LPM((uint16_t)(address_short))
...
#define   __LPM(addr)                         __LPM_enhanced__(addr)
...
#define __LPM_enhanced__(addr)  \
(__extension__({                \
    uint16_t __addr16 = (uint16_t)(addr); \
    uint8_t __result;           \
    __asm__                     \
    (                           \
        "lpm %0, Z" "\n\t"      \
        : "=r" (__result)       \
        : "z" (__addr16)        \
    );                          \
    __result;                   \
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link you posted, the macro is defined as:

```
#define   pgm_read_byte(address_short)        pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)
#define   pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)   __LPM((uint16_t)(address_short))
```

Those macros should be portable without any problems, they're simply aliasing the names of other functions/macros.  What *specifically* are you having trouble with?  What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is even __LPM((uint16_t)(address_short)) is not exist in C18 (it more used as `pgm_read_byte`) so im looking for solution or workaround.

Comment: @Maxwell- That's a different problem entirely.  You're not having problems with porting this macro, you're wanting to port a function that happens to be called by the macro.  If you can provide the body of the original __LPM function along with with your ported version, we might be able to pass along some tips.

Comment: sorry, maybe the question was not clear enough(i was too sleepy in night). i have added the body of _LPM in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Maxwell- Please also post what you have come up with so far.  What specific part of this are you having problems with?  The data types? Assembly? gcc-specific extensions?

Comment: i have adopted another code to port; this macro is very processor-specific. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

AVR is Harvard architecture and pgm_read_ macros serves to access AVR's flash memory which resides in an other address space than RAM.

On a target with a linear address space you can just use the pointers to access the data:

```
#if defined (__GNUC__) && defined (__AVR__)
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#define PROGMEM /* empty */
#define pgm_read_byte(x) (*(x))
#define pgm_read_word(x) (*(x))
#define pgm_read_float(x) (*(x))
...
#endif
```